# RStudio Desktop 0.98.1006 for Windows unable to access mapped network drives

Tags: r, rstudio, mapped-drive

Recently I updated my RStudio Desktop for Windows to the latest version 0.98.953. When running a previously working script accessing data stored on a mapped network drive (university personal file store), error occurred saying the specified path did not exist, which was not true - the directories and files were all accessible from Windows Explorer.

Further investigations showed that there were crosses on the concerned drive icons in RStudio's File - Open File... dialogue box.  However, using dir() to display these files in the native R GUI was OK, suggesting that it was a problem of RStudio's.  I have uninstalled, reinstalled RStudio and updated to the latest Version 0.98.1006 but the problem persisted.

I searched the RStudio community forums but only found one similar case reported (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200655286-RStudio-can-t-see-my-network-directory?locale=en-us) and no practical reply. Could anyone with similar experience help me with this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem with Version 0.98.1074 and also with eclipse: 
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/612569/

My (increasingly annoying) workaround is to manually open the mapped network drive, which works for both eclipse and RStudio. After initialization accessing files from the mapped network drive works perfectly.

Best regards

Comment: I have the same problem. How does one open the mapped network drive, exactly?